# the openwheather api is not working in react js while url showing data in browser

Tags: reactjs, axios

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import './App.css';
import axios from 'axios'
const api=axios.create({
  baseURL:'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Karachi&appid=e3f8864274e67280b3ee8eb501d3718a'
})



export class App extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    api.get('/').then(res=>{
      console.log(res.data)
    })
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
       <h1>React Weather App</h1>
       <main>
       </main>
       <footer>
       </footer> 
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App
```

the above code is related to wheather app. the url is showing data in the browser but not working and showing error: xhr.js:177 GET https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Karachi&appid=e3f8864274e67280b3ee8eb501d3718a/ 401 (Unauthorized)

Answer (score 1):

this error 401 (Unauthorized) is because you have wrong "appid" or expired.

Check this page for more info: https://openweathermap.org/appid

Comment: What will be the solution?

Comment: Check this page for more info: https://openweathermap.org/appid

Comment: but with the similar appid (mentioned above in the code) I'm getting correct results in the browser. meaning that appid is correct i think.

Comment: I dont know that API, but If you are receiving this error (401 (Unauthorized)) IS NOT correct key or you dont have access to that resource. 
Please check this to understand 401 error : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/401

Comment: Check this page, this the FAQ page:
https://openweathermap.org/faq#:~:text=You%20can%20get%20the%20error,API%20key%20in%20API%20request.&text=For%20example%2C%2016%20days%2Fdaily,subscription%20in%20your%20personal%20account.

Comment: You can get the error 401 in the following cases:

You did not specify your API key in API request.
Your API key is not activated yet. Within the next couple of hours, it will be activated and ready to use.

You are using wrong API key in API request. Please, check your right API key in personal account.

Comment: You are using a Free subscription and try requesting data available in other subscriptions . For example, 16 days/daily forecast API, any historical weather data, Weather maps 2.0,. Please, check your subscription in your personal account

Comment: Your welcome,, I hope my comments could help you,, have a good day !

Comment: how can I use the free services available? it will be appreciated if you guide.

Comment: so far i have seen on other platforms and youtube videos they all showing the same method for API.

Comment: the way to call the endpoint isnt the problem. Please, check their FAQ, they explained very well you doubt about issues with the appId. This is the link: 
https://openweathermap.org/faq#:~:text=You%20can%20get%20the%20error,API%20key%20in%20API%20request.&text=For%20example%2C%2016%20days%2Fdaily,subscription%20in%20your%20personal%20account